# My ArrayList will not clear

Tags: android, arraylist, swiperefreshlayout

I have an application with RecyclerView and CardView to show some items in my main page (Fragment).

I want to refresh the data with SwipeRefreshLayout.

In `SwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener` I try to do this for refreshing:
1- First clear the RecyclerViews ArrayList
2- Then loading data (`getData()`)

But the `ArrayList.clear()` sometimes will not clear the list completely!

Some times it will clear completely, some times that need two times for swipe the Refresher and even some times that needs three times!!!!

What should I exactly do???

This is just my clearing code in the Swipe Refresh (i don't have a problem in loading data):

```
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh()
        {

            listCars.clear();

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced some weird behaviour regarding `notifyDataSetChanged()` and `RecyclerView` adapters, the way I do it now is call this method in you `onRefresh()` method

```
adapter.updateData(newData);
```

And have this method in my adapter

```
public void updateData(List<Foo> newData) {
    this.mDataSet = newData;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

For some reason `notifyDataSetChanged();` called outside the adapter doesn't work all the time.

Comment: are you sure its for updating??  i have just problem with clearing

Comment: You only want to clear the list because you are loading new data, correct? So that is the same as updating.

Comment: and what should i do for clearing the list completly??

i need clearing in other project

Comment: create a method in your adapter `public void clearData() { this.mDataSet.clear(); notifyDatasSetChanged(); }`? The whole point of my answer was that `notifyDataSetChanged()` called from outside your adapter (like you did) doesn't always work for me and inside the adapter it does.